# Time Series Decompose, Specify no Trend

Tags: forecasting

I transformed my daily data using `LN(Day/PreviousDay)*100` from 2015 until 2017. I am trying the get rid of the Daily and Monthly Seasonality, so I can was going to use `msts` and `tbats`.

```
msts <- msts(ts$log_return,seasonal.periods = c(7,30.5,365.25),start = 
decimal_date(as.Date("2015-01-01")))
tbats <- tbats(msts,use.trend = FALSE)
plot(tbats, main="Multiple Season Decomposition")
```

The problem is its giving a really weird trend, it should more be like a flat line.

[image: See Decomposition]

Any Idea how I can specify the trend to be as a simple straight line with a value of 0 ?

At least suspect the trend to be 0. Here its clearly is not correct, or am I completly wrong?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I reformatted your question a little and embedded the image. Where exactly in your plot do you expect the flat line? Can you add this information to your question using the edit function?

Comment: Thanks, I edited. I was talking about level which represents the trend.

Comment: Look at the vertical scale. It is flat compared to the data.